# Get users zipcode using facebook javascript api

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook login with my website, Everything works fine but for getting the users zipcode. I would like to get users zip code. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: The API does not give you access to information like that any more.

Comment: Yup, I have been trying all day to get that with not much info, Just wanted a confirmation, thanks for that.

Comment: @CBroe Please send your comment as an actual answer so the question may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not give you access to information like that any more.

---

AFAIK, it was possible some time ago, to access a user’s address details (with their permission) – but Facebook has since disabled that. Most likely, because the data was misused by advertisers, I’d guess.