# Get user zip from Graph API with android sdk?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, reverse-geocoding

Is it possible to get a user's (The current facebook authenticated user) zip code from the Facebook sdk for android? I can return back the city, state. Which is fine but I don't want to have to add a whole maps api just to get a simple translation of city state to zip. Any suggestions? I see that this used to be possible with the Rest api but it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible because a city/state can have multiple zip codes associated with them.  You would need their specific address to determine their zip code, and Facebook does not have that.

Comment: Not to combat your answer, but how was it previously available? When they restructured did they make this information unavailable?

Comment: I'm curious about this - do you have any source or links to prove that it was available prior?  AFAIK, to use Facebook users do not input their zipcode or their street address which means FB has no way of determining an user's zip code in the first place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514593/get-users-zipcode-using-facebook-javascript-api


Looks like it may have only been javascript.